# Is there an efficient way to do image transitions in a UIImageView in xcode?

Tags: xcode, image, animation, transition

I learned how to create smooth transitions between views with the 'UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp' as shown below.

Is there a similar way to transition between images that are being switched within a single UIImageView thats in a View?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.window    cache:YES];
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:view2];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is the code I am using to switch images currently:

```
[lblSwipe setText:@"Left Swiped."];
     currentImageIndex++;
     if (currentImageIndex == [imagesArray count]) {
         currentImageIndex = 0;
     }

     [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray     objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex]]];
}
```

How would I adapt the code for my particular situation?

Comment: Can't you use the same code with your `UIImageView` objects instead of the `UIView` objects?

Comment: That's my question because the syntax relates specifically for View transitions and not UIImageView transitions UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp

Comment: `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView` so it should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm giving it a shot now. I'm not sure how to adapt the code for switching the image instead of a view. I'll keep messing with it. Thanks-

Comment: Instead of `view1` and `view2`, put your image views. Also, change `window` to `self.view`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We talked about this in the comments, but I'll post an official answer:

You can use the same code you are using to animate transitions between `UIView` objects to animate between `UIImageView` objects since `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`.